# Is saying "bucolic countryside" redundant?

Tags: word-choice

Good morning/afternoon/evening, linguistic aficionados,

My title is fairly self-explanatory. I would like to give a review for a local park. I would like my review to say something to the effect of, "A quiet, small rural park in the bucolic countryside of Michigan's Thumb region".

Is "bucolic countryside" redundant? Should I use the following review instead? "A quiet, small rural park in a bucolic setting in Michigan's Thumb region.".

Comment: **Bucolic** is hardly apt for a "local park".

Comment: Not all countryside is bucolic. Personally, I don't find it objectionable.  Countryside can be not particularly pretty or inviting....in some cases. It could be wild, rough, overgrown, and less filled with flowers, fields and trees.

Comment: Perhaps Michigan's Thumb is more industrially agricultural than bucolic. It's a rare place that can be described as that these days. If you are writing a review or a guide book, please don't romanticise to deceive your readers.

Comment: It may not be technically redundant, but it's not really a useful phrase, rather like saying a "square quadrilateral." All bucolic settings are in the "countryside," but as is pointed out above, not all countryside is bucolic. Besides a "setting," it might be a "locale," a "destination" (for a guidebook) but the fact that you are already finding appropriate use for the word bucolic to give you pause or raise a challenge tends to suggest that use of this word here may also mislead or confuse your intended audience.

Comment: I am also wonder if bucolic is right - I'd have very high standards for the word and it doesn't deliver as much as something like "A quiet, small rural park surrounded by  the small farms and with well kept tree shaded farm houses common to Michigan's Thumb region.  (my impression from a satellite map) -  for bucolic I'd wand meandering tree lined roads and cow speckled hills or something a bit more perhaps and even then a few other words would do you better than "bucolic countryside"

Comment: Who cares if it is redundant; redundancy is not ungrammatical; sometimes "redundancy" is used for emphasis.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

bucolic  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/bucolic)

> Of or characteristic of the **countryside**

Thus:

> "A quiet, small rural park in a bucolic setting in Michigan's Thumb
>   region."

is better.

Comment: a +1 for me to counter the down-vote.   If he must use bucolic I am won over to the idea that bucolic and countryside are redundant .  While not all countrysides are bucolic, bucolic mean's countryside to such a great degree and as a norm that using both is more cloying than bucolic alone (which is already a bit trite unless a person really really means it)